# Display data in Stata loop

Tags: loops, stata

I have a loop in Stata 12 that looks at each record in a file and if it finds a `flag` equal to 1 it generates five imputed values. My code looks like this:

```
forvalues i=1/5 {
 gen y3`i' = y2
 gen double h`i' = (uniform()*(1-a)+a) if flag==1
 replace y3`i' = 1.6*(invibeta(7.2,2.6,h`i')/(1-invibeta(7.2,2.6,h`i')))^(1/1.7) if 
   flag==1
 }
```

`a` is defined elsewhere. I want to check the individual imputations.  Thus, I need to display the imputed variable preferably only for those cases where `flag`=1.  I also would like to display another value, `s`, alongside.  I need help in figuring out the syntax.  I've tried every combination of quotes and subscripts that I can think of, but I keep getting error messages.

One other useful modification occurs to me.  Suppose I have three concatenated files on which I want to perform this routine.  Let them have a variable file equal to 1, 2 or 3.  I'd like to set a separate seed for each and do it in my program so I have a record.  I envision something like:

```
forvalues j=1/3 {
set seed=12345 if file=1
set seed=56789 if file=2
set seed=98765 if file=3

insert code above

}
```

Will this work?

Comment: Excellent.  Now suppose I wish to place this in a script.  Stata will flag y31 as existing.  A simple , replace does not resolve the error.  How can I get around that without clearing and reloading my data set?

Comment: You must `drop` all of `y31` ... `y35` before the loop for this to work. Or change the first `generate` into `replace`. (`generate` does not have a `replace` option if that is what you tried.) (But in general please don't ask new questions in comments.)

Answer (score 3):

No comment is possible on code you don't show, but the word "display" may be misleading you.

```
  list y3`i' if flag == 1
```

or some variation may be what you seek. Note that `display` is geared to showing at most one line of output at a time.

P.S. As you are William Shakespeare, know that the mug http://www.stata.com/giftshop/much-ado-mug/ was inspired by your work.

Answer (score 0):

A subsidiary question asks about choosing a different seed each time around a loop. That is easy:

```
  forval j = 1/3 { 
       local seed : word `j' of 12345 56789 98765 
       set seed `seed' 
       ...
  }
```

or

```
  tokenize 12345 56789 98765 
  forval j = 1/3 { 
         set seed ``j'' 
         ...
  }
```